# Java applets not starting in IE on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, java, remote-desktop-services, internet-explorer-10

I can't get the Java ActiveX Add-on to work on a Remote Desktop Server 2008 R2 with *Desktop Experience* enabled. This is what I get after enabling compatibility mode from http://www.java.com/verify :

[image: Java Verify page presenting an empty rectangle instead of the Java applet]

Other java applets embedded in web pages (most notably our SAP NetWeaver stuff) are broken, too.

I have tried:

- different versions of Java Runtime from 1.7u45 to 1.7u60
- Internet Explorer 10 as well as Internet Explorer 11
- checking the add-on state in IE's `Manage add-ons` dialog and disabling/re-enabling the two JRE-related add-ons
- disabling and re-enabling of `Java Content in the Browser` via the Java control panel
- running the browser as an administrative user after disabling *protected mode*
- performing various restarts of the Internet Explorer, Windows Explorer and the Windows OS

but I never received a result any different to what's shown in the screenshot above. What did I do to deserve that?

Comment: Are you installing the 32-bit or 64-bit JRE?

Comment: @dartonw 64-bit. IE 10 and 11 are both 64-bit editions, too.

Comment: Check your environment variables; ensure that the JRE installation directory is in your %PATH% and that %JAVA_HOME% is set. You could try 32-bit also; I've had issues with IE 32-bit running instead of 64, even when 64 was launched explicitly.

Comment: @dartonw Neither is the case. I believe, the JRE installer is simply not setting it. But how would the IE ActiveX Addon for Java be affected by environment variables?

Comment: After following your advice to install 32-bit JRE, it magically worked. It appears that even x64-Windows IE is running as a 32-bit process unless [*"Enhanced Protected Mode"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/03/14/enhanced-protected-mode.aspx) is activated. Please do post it as an answer, so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer only uses its 64-bit executable when the browser setting "Enhanced Protected Mode" is enabled on the Security tab. Otherwise the 32-bit executable is used, and the corresponding 32-bit JRE must be installed:

[image: iexplore.exe running in 32-bit mode]

From [Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx):

> In Internet Explorer on the Desktop, by default, Content Processes
>   remain at 32bit by default for compatibility with 32bit ActiveX
>   controls, Toolbars, BHOs, etc. Even when you directly launch the 64bit
>   iexplore.exe executable, you will still have a 64bit Manager Process
>   that hosts only 32bit Content Processes. If you want to enable 64bit
>   Content Processes for the Desktop, you must tick the **Enable Enhanced**
>   **Protected Mode** option in the Security section of Internet Explorer’s
>   **Tools > Internet Options > Advanced** tab. When this option is enabled,
>   all Content Processes that are running in Protected Mode (e.g.
>   Internet Zone and Restricted Zone, by default) will begin to use 64bit
>   Content Processes.

Answer (score 0):

Java Verify failure  unable to Configure Java Control Panel does not open ( Fix : ) 
this is a regular ( windows 7 bug related ) problem after successful installation of Java ( jre ) and fresh installation of Windows7 64bit or 32bit on my laptop or desktop.  what worked perfectly for me was setting  COMPATIBILITYMODE=WINDOWSNT  to make windows launch the JP2LAUNCHER.EXE  and  JAVAW.EXE  files properly.
jp2launcher.exe windowsNT compatibility solves Java Verify failure problem at  https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
javaw.exe windowsNT compatibility solves unable to open or Configure Java Control Panel problem.

```
*  search for JAVAW.EXE   inside  c:\program files\java\....\bin   
      or  c:\program files(x86)\java\.....\bin\
*  right-click mouse on  JAVAW   application icon logo
*  click  PROPERTIES
*  click  COMPATIBILITY
*  tick the checkbox at COMPATIBILITY MODE
*  choose  WINDOWS NT service pack
*  click APPLY or click OK
```

Now, the Configure Java Control Panel will start opening and working.

```
*  search for JP2LAUNCHER.EXE   inside  c:\program files\java\....\bin   
      or  c:\program files(x86)\java\.....\bin\
*  right-click mouse on  JP2LAUNCHER
*  click  PROPERTIES
*  click  COMPATIBILITY
*  tick the checkbox at COMPATIBILITY MODE
*  choose  WINDOWS NT service pack
*  click APPLY or click OK
```

Now, the Verify Java will be successful at  https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

if we find 2 or 3 versions of JP2LAUNCHER and JAVAW when we search, then we must repeat the above for all of them.

in the Configure Java Control Panel Advanced tab we can set "Do not check" certificate revocation and disable security verification. and in the Security tab we may Edit Site List... for the Exception Site List  ( add URLs to  unblock sites )